# What Is Causing this Error with Terraform ECR Import?

Tags: terraform, aws-ecr

I've got a big-ish Terraform project, with state split into a half-dozen different state files, and a lot of modules that make up the codebase. I am trying to do an import of an AWS ECR repository, but am getting an error about the `repositoryName` field, but I do not see such a property available in [the ECR Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecr_repository.html).

Comment: What command are you running and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I was no @hacklan07. Wound up deleting existing & replacing with one I terraform'd